# Scrollable/zoomable view in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, pinchzoom

In iOS, since 2.0 in 2008, there's the UIScrollView class to provide a view that the user can pinch zoom and drag around.

Is there an equivalent class in Android Jellybean and up?

I've found some questions here, where the answer is to make a custom class containing all the programming needed to detect the pinching and dragging, and then adjust an ImageView accordingly.

Is this really the way to go for such a basic touch screen function?

Comment: I know about ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView, but they only support either vertical or horizontal scrolling, not both at the same time.

Comment: What is your content?

Comment: The zoomable view should contain two ImageViews that both fill the entire view. (The image on top is partly transparent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try the one of the following libraries, depending on what kind of content you need to handle:

### **1. Generic Zoomable View**: https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view

Just wrap you content with an instance of ZoomView:

```
//...
ZoomView zoomView zoomView = new ZoomView(getActivity());
zoomView.addView(contentInflatedView);
//add zoomView to your layout...
```

### 2.  Zoomable ImageView: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: What I need to achieve, is to have a zoomable drawing that is made up two layered ImageViews. One on top containing an outline with transparency, and the other beneath, coloring. So when the user zooms and drags, these should both scale and move as one. I also need to capture the x,y coordinate of taps on the drawing. Will your suggestion #1 work for this? I.e., if the ZoomView class takes care of scaling and moving the zoomview, will ImageViews that I put inside it also scale with it?